# No Video Feed from FPV camera on Matrice 210

Tags: dji-sdk

I am using the IOS Mobile SDK and have been unable to see the live video feed from the M210 (app works fine using the Mavic Air).  I am using a modified version of the sample camera app so, something like:

```
   if ((product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameA3)
        || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameN3)
        || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600)
        || (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice600Pro)){
        DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.secondaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
    }else{
        DJISDKManager.videoFeeder()?.primaryVideoFeed.add(self, with: nil)
    }
    VideoPreviewer.instance().start()
}
```

I actually tried adding the M210 into the if statement to use the secondary video feed but that didn't work either.  Is there anything else that needs to be handled different with the M210 versus the Mavic?

Comment: I have also been trying to get the FPV camera feed, and I found that the `airlink.isLightbridgeLinkSupported` property returned false. Is this also happening to you? (I don't know how to fix it, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

For M210, the `primaryVideoFeed` and the `secondaryVideoFeed` depend on the bandwidth allocation that has been set.

Check out these interfaces and their description to get an idea of how exactly the video feeds are managed:

[`setBandwidthAllocationForMainCamera`](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/LBAirLink/DJILBAirLink.html?search=bandwidth&i=19&#djilbairlink_setbandwidthallocationforleftcamera_inline): Sets the percentage downlink video bandwidth dedicated to the main camera or main cameras (for M210 and M210 RTK). The remaining percentage is dedicated to the FPV camera. For M210 and M210 RTK, the bandwidth for main cameras can be further divided by calling `setBandwidthAllocationForLeftCamera`.

[`setBandwidthAllocationForLeftCamera`](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/LBAirLink/DJILBAirLink.html#djilbairlink_setbandwidthallocationforleftcamera_inline): Sets the percentage of the main cameras' bandwidth dedicated to the left camera. The remaining percentage is dedicated to the right camera. The main cameras' bandwidth is determined by setBandwidthAllocationForMainCamera. 
This setting will influence the physical sources of video feeds (getPrimaryVideoFeed and getSecondaryVideoFeed):

- When bandwidth is 100% on the left camera, the primary source is LEFT_CAM and the secondary source is FPV_CAM.
- When bandwidth 0% on the left camera, the primary source is RIGHT_CAM and the secondary source is FPV_CAM.
- When bandwidth is neither 0% nor 100% on the left camera, the primary source is LEFT_CAM and the secondary source is RIGHT_CAM. It is only supported by M210 and M210 RTK.

---

For your problem, I think the bandwidth of the drone might be set to incorrect values, so please set the bandwidth manually before fetching the video feeds; that should work. Try setting the main bandwidth to be 80% and left bandwidth to be 100% (if you have only one camera).

Comment: Ok, I have added the bandwidth setting, but still see darkness.  I set it as follows:   if (product?.model == DJIAircraftModelNameMatrice210) {
            Aircraft.aircraft?.airLink?.lightbridgeLink?.setBandwidthAllocationForLeftCamera(1.0, withCompletion: nil)
            Aircraft.aircraft?.airLink?.lightbridgeLink?.setBandwidthAllocationForMainCamera(0.8, withCompletion: nil)
        }